# How to: Standalone C# printing on Epson Thermal printer

Tags: c#, desktop-application, thermal-printer, epson

For the first time I've been given this Thermal printer (M325A) to use, at this stage I have ZERO idea of how to code my desktop application to print "ANYTHING". But my present requirement will be to print just 4 lines of information:-

Pre-mentioned Static Banner (Big text),

User supplied numeric value (Non-Decimals),

Serial Number (Progressive),

Current Date & Time.

Kindly help me start.

Comment: from [here](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/) you get apparently documentation, drivers and probably all that you need to find out how the communication with this device works. If nothing helps, I would suggest to directly conntact the tech support of epson. I usually do that, and in almost all cases they are very eager to help. Because they want to leave a good impression, so that you buy more of their stuff ;)

Comment: [here is the documentation](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_doc&cid=5171&dcat=23&pcat=3)

Comment: Probably the easiest way to use this library. [lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET)

Answer (score -1):

While there are printing libraries out there, you can as well directly connect to the printer, over serial, USB, or, ethernet, and send it the commands to print.  ESC/POS capable printers interpret escape sequences, which are very well documented.  You must, however, get to know how you can send binary data (i.e. 8-bit bytes) directly to the printer.